# How do I use Google re-marketing ads on YouTube to show three ads to a user sequentially with time inbetween?

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads, youtube, remarketing

I am trying to setup a campaign to perform re-marketing on YouTube.
I currently have 3 ads and ad groups. Let's call them ad1, ad2 and ad3. My goal is this:

- If a user has visited the site, and hasn't seen an ad in the last 48 hours, and hasn't seen ad1, show them ad1.
- If a user has visited the site, and hasn't seen an ad in the last 48 hours, and hasn't seen ad2, show them ad2.
- If a user has visited the site, and hasn't seen an ad in the last 48 hours, and hasn't seen ad3, show them ad3.

I want the re-marketing ads to be shown in this particular order (1, 2 and then 3).

I'm struggling to achieve this using google ads. I can create an audience of users that have visited the site + haven't seen adX.
What I cannot seem to do is figure out how to show them ads based on a specific rotation. For example, if I have a user that has visited the site and seen no ads, it seems like a total crapshoot which ad group they will get thrown into, and google will try to "optimize" and show them the best performing ad, when what I want is to show them ads in a specific order.

Moreover, I can't seems to come up with a reasonable way to space out these ads with 48 hours in between. Under the campaign, I can set an impression cap, but it only allows me to cap the impressions per user at once per day/per week/per month. There is no way to space with more granularity, e.g. every 48 hours.